# jQuery Ajax call to a php function corrupts JSON data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, utf-8

I send an email with a jQuery ajax call to a php function. Format is UTF-8 and the E-Mail is sent ok. But in the data that the server function receives ($message) there is an additional new line every about 1000 to 1200 characters.

On example: (a new line between "und si" and "e sich"):

```
{
                "content": "Vielen war es einfach zu viel Aufwand, zu verschlüsseln. Oder sie waren einfach träge. Sie wollten nicht verschlüsseln, weil es Zeit kostete und si

e sich in etwas Neues hineindenken mussten.",
```

The javascript-code:

```
var factString = JSON.stringify(fact);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "email.php",
    data: "json="+factString+"&thought="+currentThought,
    success: function(r){
        $('#send_thought .buttontext').html("GEDANKE WEGGESCHICKT!");
    }
});
```

php:

```
<?php

ini_set( 'default_charset', 'UTF-8' );
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

if($_POST){
    $thought = $_POST['thought'];
    $message = utf8_decode($_POST['json']);

//send email
    mail("michael@primaerarbeit.de", "Gedanke ".$thought." von CP11", $message);

    print("Sent thought ".$thought."!");
}
?>
```

Comment: why there isn't $message = utf8_decode(json_decode($_POST['json'])); in Your code?

Comment: Its a string. Why should I decode it as if it were json? I tried and it returns an error...

Comment: why are you posting as JSON string? and why is `data` a string and not an object?

Comment: _“Only every about 1000 to 1200 characters there is a additional new line in the email text.”_ – in the data your server side script gets passed, or in the email that is received?

Comment: In the data that the server side gets past ...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you want to use the following:

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "email.php",
    data: {
        fact: fact,
        thought: currentThought
    },
    success: function(r){
        $('#send_thought .buttontext').html("GEDANKE WEGGESCHICKT!");
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php

ini_set( 'default_charset', 'UTF-8' );
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

if($_POST){
    $thought = $_POST['thought'];
    $message = utf8_decode($_POST['fact']);

    //send email
    mail("michael@primaerarbeit.de", "Gedanke ".$thought." von CP11", $message);

    print("Sent thought ".$thought."!");
}
?>
```

Comment: I made the change with the parameters, and it also works and is nicer. But it still puts in the new lines every 1000 to 12oo characters.

Comment: At what stage do you see the new lines? Already in the `$_POST`? after `utf8_decode` or in the email you receive?

Answer (score 0):

From php-documentation:

"The maximum total length of a text line including the  is 1000 characters" (RFC 821)

My solution was to use "wordwrap":

```
<?php

ini_set( 'default_charset', 'UTF-8' );
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

if($_POST){
    $thought = $_POST['thought'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = utf8_decode($_POST['json']);

    $message = wordwrap($message);
    $message = str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $message);

    mail("michael@primaerarbeit.de, ".$email, "Gedanke ".$thought." von ".$email, $message);

    print("Sent thought ".$message."!");
}
?>
```